# A topic on freebase has only one notable type?

Tags: types, freebase

I just noticed that now when you request the data of a topic on freebase (using the browser or the API) you only get one notable type. This wasn't like that before.

For example, if I get the info of the empire state building http://www.freebase.com/m/02nd_

You will see that it only has "skyscraper" as notable type. Not so far ago, in that array you were able to see also other types like "structure","building" or "tourist attraction".

Why can't I get those types anymore? Is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself, I post the solution in case someone has the same problem.

Freebase API still provides those notable types but they made some changes (Interface of the page and API behavior) and that's why I was not able to find them.

- The change in the interface: (You can see the example following the link in the question)

The notable types are listed within a column on the right part of the page instead of being under the section "notable types" on the left main column of the page.

- The change in the API:

Before it was possible to get these types from the property "/common/topic/notable_types". Now you can get them the same way but from the property "/type/object/type". You can test it with the following link (just replacing your Freebase API key on it)

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02nd_?lang=en&key=YourFreebaseAPIKey&filter=/common/topic/notable_types&filter=/type/object/type

Finally, if you are filtering the properties in the request to Freebase API to get only some properties, don't forget to add the filter "/type/object/type" to the request or, of course, you will not be able to get it from the response.